# Using SOQL apex bind variables for date literals (e.g. LAST_N_DAYS, TODAY, THIS_QUARTER)

Tags: apex, soql

Is there anyway I can use a variable value for LAST_N_DAYS. For example, I am trying to do something like:

```
Integer lastDays = 7;
//... 
//...
List<Opportunity> opportunities = [SELECT OwnerId, Amount, Probability FROM OPPORTUNITY 
where Amount > 0 and LastModifiedDate < LAST_N_DAYS:lastDays];
```

But I get:

```
expecting a number, found 'lastDays'
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Wow, that's an interesting one! I doubt it's allowed though (at least without having to use Dynamic SOQL).

You can always do this instead:

```
Date d = System.today() - 7;
List<Opportunity> opportunities = [SELECT OwnerId, Amount, Probability FROM OPPORTUNITY 
where Amount > 0 and LastModifiedDate < :d];
```

Comment: Good answer.  This is a little more complicated when you want to use a variable for N in a date range like `LastModifiedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:N`.

Comment: I would use `Date.today().addDays(-7)` and let the Date object handle all of the inherent terribleness of arithmetic on calendar dates for you :)

Answer (score 14):

You can use `Database.query()` with a string like:

```
Integer lastDays = 7;

List<OPPORTUNITY> opplist = Database.query('SELECT OwnerId, Amount, Probability FROM OPPORTUNITY where Amount > 0 and LastModifiedDate < LAST_N_DAYS:' + lastDays);

System.debug(opplist);
```

This is referred to as [Dynamic SOQL](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_soql.htm).

Answer (score 1):

It would be great if you could, but you can't. At least not in any way I'm aware of. When I need this, I build up dynamic SOQL. The date arithmetic eyescream mentions is another solution, although make sure you do thorough testing as date arithmetic is much more bug-prone than SOQL date literals.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly query it like:

```
List<Opportunity> opportunities = [SELECT OwnerId, Amount, Probability FROM OPPORTUNITY 
where Amount > 0 and LastModifiedDate < LAST_N_DAYS:7];
```

No need to declare variable and its value first,