# How to use Custom Setting variable in LAST_N_DAYS

Tags: apex, soql, customsetting

I am trying to write a SOQL query which uses the Custom Settings. Basically, trying to query all the records of a Custom Object of the last 30 days. I am trying to use a custom setting Number_Days__c of List type where 'Days__c' field is 30.

When I am trying this in an anonymous window but getting Error as Unexpected token '=' on line 6

```
Number_Days__c nd = Number_Days__c.getValues('Test');
System.debug(nd);
Integer xnd = Integer.valueOf(nd.Days__c);
System.debug(xnd);//Works fine
List<CustomObject__c> ds = new List<CustomObject__c> ();
ds = [select Id, Name from CustomObject__c where CreatedDate < LAST_N_DAYS:xnd]; //Error on this line
System.debug(rps);
```

What is it that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Hi! It seems that what you want to do is not supported. But there's a workaround. Try this solution: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7515/using-soql-apex-bind-variables-for-date-literals-e-g-last-n-days-today-this

Comment: Something else you can try is converting your query to Dynamic SOQL, see this document: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm

Comment: @SergioPedrazaJ. - you should write this up as an answer

Comment: Done. Thanks @cropredy

Answer (score 0):

As Sergio said, try this way

```
String query = 'Select Id, Name from CustomObject__c';
query += ' where CreatedDate < LAST_N_DAYS:' +xnd;

For(CustomObject__c myObj : Database.query(query)){
    // do your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you want to do is not supported. But there's a workaround. Try this solution: [Using SOQL apex bind variables for date literals (e.g. LAST_N_DAYS, TODAY, THIS_QUARTER)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7515/using-soql-apex-bind-variables-for-date-literals-e-g-last-n-days-today-this)

Something else you can try is converting your query to Dynamic SOQL, see this document: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm

Comment: @Accredo2442 don't forget to select the correct answer if it worked for you! Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, while it has no bearing on the issue you are struggling with, I *highly recommend* you use whole words for all your variable naming. Also irrelevant to the issue you are struggling with is that you should avoid adding new `List Custom Settings`. If you are defining application defaults, consider a `Hierarchy Custom Setting` instead. Otherwise, use `Custom Metadata`.

---

That said, you can declare a `Datetime` variable and use that as your threshold in the calculation. You can adjust the hours/minutes/seconds down to 0 if your query needs to be that sensitive, but the basic idea would be:

```
Integer days = (Integer)My_Setting__c.getOrgDefaults().My_Days_Field__c;
Datetime threshold = Datetime.now().addDays(-days);
List<My_Object__c> records = [SELECT Name FROM My_Object__c WHERE CreatedDate < :threshold];
```