# How to Change CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:N in a query to a custom setting variable

Tags: apex, soql, customsetting, createddate

I am trying to change a hard coded created date time range from a query to a custom setting. When applying the custom setting variable, the list return empty. Here is the original query:

```
SELECT Id, Name, CreatedDate FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:30 ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
```

Here is how the query should look like:

```
  SELECT Id, Name, CreatedDate
  FROM Account
  WHERE CreatedDate = :creationDate
  ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
```

The custom setting has the label of **Number of days** and the API name is *numberOfDays__c* with a number field label **Report Days Range** with the API name of *Report_Days_Range__c*. The Default org value is 30 and no setup owner as seen in the image below.
[[image: Custom Setting Values1]

[image: Default Organization Level Value]

Here is my code:

```
numberOfDays__c customSetting = numberOfDays__c.getInstance();
Integer customSettingReportDaysRange = Integer.valueOf(
  customSetting.Report_Days_Range__c
);
Date creationDate = System.today() - customSettingReportDaysRange;

List<Account> accountReportList;

accountReportList = [
  SELECT Id, Name, CreatedDate
  FROM Account
  WHERE CreatedDate = :creationDate
  ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
];

//Debug statements to confirm that everything is working
System.debug(
  'Custom Setting number value: ' + customSettingReportDaysRange
);
System.debug('Custom Setting date: ' + creationDate);
System.debug('Account report list: ' + accountReportList);
```

I have tried the solution offered in another post: [Using SOQL apex bind variables for date literals (e.g. LAST_N_DAYS, TODAY, THIS_QUARTER)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7515/using-soql-apex-bind-variables-for-date-literals-e-g-last-n-days-today-this) however, the query returns empty.

The main goal is to return a report of accounts where the time created was in the past 30 days.

Thank you in advance

Comment: `WHERE CreatedDate = :creationDate` -- are you trying to get only Accounts created exactly 30 days ago? or Accounts created 30,29,28, ...0 days ago? (if the latter, you need a `>=` operator. Also CreatedDate is a Datetime field, not a Date

Comment: Thank you so much! You solved it. I can't believe I had the wrong DateTime type! Since I needed the lasted accounts created within the past 30 days I will use `>=`

Answer (score 2):

- `CreatedDate` is `DateTime`, not `Date`
- You probably want all `Accounts` created within the last 30 days, not exactly 30 days ago

so ...

```
DateTime creationDate = System.now().addDays(-customSettingReportDaysRange);

List<Account> accountReportList;

accountReportList = [
  SELECT Id, Name, CreatedDate
  FROM Account
  WHERE CreatedDate >= :creationDate
  ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
];
```

or, in 1 line

```
Account[] accountReportList = 
   SELECT Id, Name, CreatedDate
     FROM Account
     WHERE CreatedDate >= :System.now().addDays(-customSettingReportDaysRange)
     ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
    ];
```

Comment: Can I ask why `-1 * customSettingReportDaysRange` if `addDays(-customSettingReportDaysRange)` and `System.today() - customSettingReportDaysRange` solves it

Comment: they all work; I edited my answer. Thanks